# Adding foreign key field to a javabean

Tags: java, database, javabeans

Consider this regular javabean without ORM/:

```
// primary key is auto incremented by the database, so I can't add it
public class User {
    String name;
    int personID; // foreign key
    // no args constructor
    // getter/setters for fields
}
```

Is it ok to do this? I personally think it doesn't make sense because there is no reason to manipulate the foreign key through the bean, but I might be wrong. Are there use cases where this is good?

Comment: Is personId the unique id to the User class or does personId reference a Person class?

Comment: @Jose Martinez personId somewhat references the Person class, but not really represented in the code. Since personId is an autoincremented field in the database, the person class does not have the personId field. That's why I think it might not be logical to put this personId foreign key in the User class, but I might be wrong because I think you can do it if you want to.

Comment: Does User have its own id?

Comment: @Jose Martinez yes, also autoincrement in the database so not present in the bean

Comment: Your bean seems awkward to me.  Why wouldn't an entity (as it were) have a reference to its ID value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally do it like this.

```
public class Person {

    private final String id;

    public Person(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class User {

    private final String id;
    private String personId;

    public User(String id, String personId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public User() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

}
```

Another alternative for User is to make it immutable.  In which case it would look something like this.

```
public class User {

    private final String id;
    private final String personId;

    public User(String id, String personId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public User(String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

}
```

Now the classes can be used in an autoincremented or non-autoincremented way.  Basically the option is there for the classes to make their own unique ID or for a unique ID to be passed to it.

One common dilemma that I have seen is when the id does not exist yet the object does.  That is the case when the object is created in the program but the ID (which maybe created by the DB when it is inserted) is not assigned to it yet.  In that case the bean may look like this.

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private final String personId;

    public User(String id, String personId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public User(String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Notice the id is not final and hence the object can exist without the id present and can be added in later if needed

Answer (score 0):

You are better off modelling the objects and their relationships to one another in an object oriented way.

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private Person person;
    // .... Removed for clarity
}
```